# iOS 10: Clear 'Up Next' Queue in Apple Music

Tags: iphone, music, ios, apple-music

I like to use **Up Next** in Apple Music on my iPhone, and sometimes I want to clear its contents to add new music to it. Earlier in iOS 9 it was possible but now I don’t see any way to do this in iOS 10.

Is it possible to **CLEAR** the ***Up Next queue***?

*(I know how to delete a single track from the queue)*

Using iPhone 7, iOS 10.2 (Public Beta)

Answer (score 1):

One workaround to clear the queue and also to play a single song:

- Quit the Music app. This will clear the "Up Next" queue.
- Find the song you want to play alone.
- Tap–hold the song to hail the contextual menu.
- Tap "Play Next". This creates a new queue for the lone song.
- Tap the queue and play the song.

I admit it's frustrating in that it interrupts music if already playing. And it's unintuitive.

https://www.apple.com/feedback/